# Attrs on one2many field based on some parent field

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I had customised "stock.picking" and added two new fields in "stock.move" and "stock.pack.operation", while creating Sale Order I will pass value for that two field from it, but while creating purchase order I will not pass value for that field.

Picking made from purchase order I don't need that two field in "stock.move" and "stock.pack.operation" so I need to hide that.

I had tried some attrs on field but I can't get expected result.

[image: See Image for Ref]

There is a `purchase_id` field in my stock.picking, so I put attrs like:

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('picking_id.purchase_id', '!=', False)]}
```

or there is a `location_id` field in stock.pack.operation, for that I tried:

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('location_id.usage', '!=', 'supplier')]}
```

Comment: Please share your code. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I Tried,
There is a purchase_id field in my stock.picking.
so i put attrs like
attrs="{'invisible': [('picking_id.purchase_id', '!=', False)]}

or there is a location_id field in stock.pack.operation, for that i tried
attrs="{'invisible': [('location_id.usage', '!=', 'supplier')]}

@Odedra

Comment: show all of your efforts/code in your question to better understand.

Comment: Updated the question now you can understand better. @Odedra

Comment: Hi @DivyangJariwala Did you find the answer, please post it here it would be a great help for me.